# Full height side bar and content with sticky footer layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple layout of page-wrap containing top menu and after it a left sidebar and a content div.
For making the layout to have a sticky footer the footer div is placed after page-wrap div.

This layout should have the following features:
1. It has a sticky footer so even if there is less text in content div the footer still remains at the bottom of the browser.
2. The sidebar is responsive so I will change its width with media queries. Now it has width 80px. The content div should fill the remaining width now and when i change the width of sidebar with media queries.
3. It would be really nice to have css which does not conflict with Twitter Bootstrap 3 css, which I am using on this site (although not used in this example and i will add later).
4. **The sidebar(red) and content(yellow) should fill the remaining height of the browser, which is my current problem and I want your kind help for.**

My layout is [here](http://softhem.se/layout/)! , A image is also [here](http://softhem.se/layout/two-col-sticky-footer.jpg)!.
Thanks for help.

```css
/* Sticky footer */
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -55px;
  background-color: #18b7f1;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 55px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
  border-top: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
}

/* Layout */
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.top-menu {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.side-bar {
    background-color: red;
    width:80px;
    float: left;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
/* This css is suggested by proPet which works fine now */
div.side-bar , div.content {
    height: calc(100vh - 105px); // 55px+50px top menu would be the height of your    site_footer and top menu
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Two Col Layout</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="page-wrap">
            <div class="top-menu"> Top menu</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            
            <div class="side-bar">
                sidebar
            </div>
            
            <div class="content">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letrasetand mently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="site-footer">
            footer
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what have you tried? Display table, floats, jQuery, Flex.

Comment: yes, Christina i tried floating, display inline, table etc and several suggestions on this site but it created some problems because all the previous solutions on this site does NOT take into account the sticky footer layout. And when i tried those solutions the side-bar would overflow the footer and sometime the footer would appear about 55px above the bottom of browser. Please note that the div with class clear is needed in this layout. If you remove the fist one the .content(yellow) overlaps .side-bar(red).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [`calc()`](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) in your CSS:

```
div.side-bar {
    height: calc(100vh - 55px); // 55px would be the height of your site_footer
}
```

Comment: Works perfect ! :) , Just to complete the question in the answer, I also added the suggested css to content class like:  div.side-bar , div.content {
    height: calc(100vh - 105px); // 55px would be the height of your site_footer
}, thanks

Comment: Works perfect ! :) , Just to complete the question in the answer, I also added the suggested css to .content class, and since the top menu height is 50px so instead 55px it should be 105px (50 topmenu + 55 footer) which will make the vertical scrol bar disappeared:  
div.side-bar , div.content {
    height: calc(100vh - 105px); // 55px+50px top menu would be the height of your site_footer and top menu
}

Comment: However there is still one problem, if the text in the .content is increased the footer appears fixed (stays always) at the bottom of the browser, Any further fix? thanks

Comment: @Sunny19 You may use javascript to set the `posision:fixed` to `posision:relative` if the `div.content`'s `height` css is greater than a certain amount. Please accept the answer above if it solved your issue. Also, please post the above comment as a new question as it is beyond the scope of the original :)

Comment: @Porphet JS is not the required solution !

Comment: @Sunny19, "**4. The sidebar(red) and content(yellow) should fill the remaining height of the browser, which is my current problem and I want your kind help for.**" - This has been answered